# How to define multiple streams from UARTs to be used in fprintf

Tags: arm, embedded, uart

I'm working with ARM (SAM4), it has two UARTs, I need to setup streams so that I could use fprintf to print on both.

Already tried `fwopen` without luck:

```c
    FILE * debug; 
    
    debug_writefn(void *cookie, const char *buf, int n);
    
    void comm_init(void) {
      debug = fwopen(NULL, &debug_writefn);
      if (debug == NULL) {
        printf("Error");
      }
      fprintf(debug, "Test");
    }
```

However, the debug_writefn is newer called.

I'm using the `arm-none-eabi-*` toolchain (I guess it uses newlib), ASF and FreeRTOS.

Comment: This question is more closely related to your compiler and the specifics of its standard library implementation than the MCU or hardware, so it would help to you what you are working with. Perhaps along with a complete example (whether you checked the error return of `fwopen` for instance). I don't suppose you could make do with the straightforward and portable workaround of writing via `snprintf` to an intermediate buffer, and then forwarding _that_ to the UARTs instead?

Comment: What toolchain? What execution environment (I.e. OS, bare metal)? Generally on bare-metal system, one has to retarget the library; there you can simply send data to the stdout or stderr streams to both ports.

Comment: You are asking for a very large pile of code to be added here so that it feels like it is not bare metal when it is most likely bare metal (are you using an RTOS).  If you just want to print strings you dont need that very large pile of C library code, you can just send the bytes to the uart(s).

Comment: Updated the question, @doynax I thought that it will be simple, so probably the `snprintf` will do, @old_timer the point is the string formating.

Comment: On all the `newlib` implementations I came across so far there is no `fwopen`. In order to redirect stdio, you need to `#define DEBUG_ENABLE` while building and simply supply a `_write` and a `_read` function that overrides the builtin do-nothings.

Answer (score 1):

You only need re-implement newlib's `_write()` or `write_r()` syscall to handle the stdout the stream file handle in any way you require, e.g.:

```c
    enum 
    {
        STDIN_HANDLE,
        STDOUT_HANDLE,
        STDERR_HANDLE
    } ;
    
    long _write( int fd, const void *buf, size_t cnt )
    {
        int ret = EOF ;
    
        if( fd == STDOUT_HANDLE || fd == STDERR_HANDLE )
        {
            for( int i = 0; i < cnt; i++ )
            {
                serialPutc( UART1, buf[i] ) ;
                serialPutc( UART2, buf[i] ) ;
            }
    
            ret = i ;
        }
    
        return ret ;
    }
```